# Replacing a specific character at the end of a string mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do i replace the last character of a string with another character only if it ends with D for example?

Comment: Step 1: [Check the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html). For example, what would you call a function that can *replace* parts of a string?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want chage you last char to X where last char = 'D'

```
    select concat(LEFT(your_col, LENGTH(left) -1), 'X' )
    FROM Your_table 
    WHERE RIGHT(your_col, 1) = 'D';
```

or for avoid multybytes  lenght problem as suggested  by spencer7593

```
    select concat(LEFT(your_col, CHAR_LENGTH(left) -1), 'X' )
    FROM Your_table 
    WHERE RIGHT(your_col, 1) = 'D';
```

Comment: we might better use `CHAR_LENGTH` function in place of `LENGTH` function if there is a possibility that `your_col` might contain multibyte characters.